# How to clear a page on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I clear the window on Tkinter? This is my code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

mGui = Tk ()
mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")
mLabel1 = Label (text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",fg = "blue",bg = "white").place (x= 150,y = 200)
mbutton = Button (text = "Next").place(x = 275,y = 230)
mGui.mbutton = (mbutton.forget())
```

Comment: I added a small bit of code and comments to the last code snippet of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is being caused by two things: you `place` the widget in the same line where you `define` the widget `name = somewidget()`, and you are not actually removing the widgets. The line `mGui.mbutton = (mbutton.forget())` is not really doing anything. You should use `command={function name}` in the widget defining line, so you can call a function when the button is clicked.

`.forget()` should work, but you are using it wrong. You should probably use something like this:

```
import sys
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def next_screen():
    mLabel1.place_forget()
    mbutton.place_forget()

mGui = tkinter.Tk()
mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")

mLabel1 = tkinter.Label(text="Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",
                        fg="blue", bg="white")
mLabel1.place(x=150, y=200)

mbutton = tkinter.Button(text="Next", command=next_screen)
mbutton.place(x=275, y=230)
```

Placing `.pack()` or `.place()` in the same line as the defining of the button or label, will cause the widget to become a `nonetype` somehow. I do not fully understand this myself, but having the `widget.place()` on a separate line helps, and you can test this yourself.

Even better would be something like a function that takes a list of widget names as an input, and will remove every one of those widgets:

```
mbutton = tkinter.Button(text="Next", command=forget_page1)
mbutton.place(x=275, y=230)

def next_screen(names):
    for widget in names:
        widget.place_forget()   

def forget_page1():
    widgets = [mLabel1, mbutton]
    next_screen(widgets)
    # Code for the creation of page2 widgets

# You could probably make a function for every page, but I'm sure
# someone could come up with a better answer, instead of repeat
# making functions.
def forget_page2():
    widgets = [page2label, page2button, image]
    next_screen(widgets)
    # Code for the creation of the widgets on page3?
```

Comment: I believe the reason .pack() doesn't work in the same line is that it deals with the object and then returns None. So, it's like saying ...
`mbutton = None`
So first you create the object and then you call the pack() method on it.

Comment: @jcfollower This is most likely the correct answer. It makes sense that it returns `none`, because saying `something = grid()` would most likely be nothing.